# Google search results showing wrong answers count

Tags: support

I was searching google for some Azure key vault issue, one question showed it’s having 2 answers. When I open it, no answer found. Some cache issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question has already been asked (and answered) on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115634/323179).

Comment: Ok thanks, I could not find it in Meta, that’s why asked..

Comment: Definitely also related: [Does Google special-case for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/136397),  [Why is Google returning answers from SO for keywords found in ads?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289905) and [Google "answering" my search with link to SE, but not showing the top answer(s)](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/233845) Google

Comment: All of these issues have one thing in common: Stack Overflow is supplying Google with the right information in the form of Schema.org markup, *which Google recommends sites use*, and Google is ignoring or incorrectly using the data. This is a problem Google needs to solve.

Comment: @Laurel Kinda ironic on that MSE question the first example actually has 3 answers now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google is doing a great job reading Schema markup. They work without problem in many cases.

But sometimes we can find these type of mistakes even we follow Google recommendation about Schema markup . This has been happened many of my client's sites also.

This is a bug on Google algorithm. So Google need to find a way to solve this.

Comment: Why it this answer downvoted and **exactly** the same written in the [comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363803/google-search-results-showing-wrong-answers-count?cb=1#comment560349_363803) is fine. Get serious meta people...

Comment: @Skipper People here just downvote without thinking, you will get use to it.